# Using makefile variables in shell script

Tags: shell, makefile

I've a makefile where all the environment variables are defined (top directory) and I want to use some of these variables in a shell script present at innermost level.

How should I access those variables in the script? Do I need to IPC for passing the variables or is there any other method to do the same?

Answer (score 6):

If `make` exports the variables, you can use them right away (but note that changes to shell variables will not change the `make` variables). If you use GNU make, you can use the `export` directive.

If `make` does not export the variable, you can use the shell's one-shot assignment, like in

```
UNEXPORTED_VAR = foo
all:
     UNEXPORTED_VAR='$(UNEXPORTED_VAR)' OTHERVAR='$(OTHERVAR)' script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Jens said is correct, export make variables can be used. But his solution is not working for me.
So what you can also do is just export them in the makefile:

```
export UNEXPORTED_VAR
```