# using makefile variables in shell script without running make

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile

We have a big make file that defines a lot of useful variables, like TEST_ENV. I'd like to make a shell script that lives in the same directory, and was wondering if there is any way to use the variables defined in the Makefile from the shell script. The variables I'm interested in are all defined like this

```
TEST_ENV := PATH=/path/to/thing \
            CONFDIR=/another/path
```

or

```
host_installdir = /still/a/path
```

The reason I want the script use the Makefile is so that if the variable ever needs to be changed inside the Makefile, the shell script won't get out of date.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645340/using-makefile-variables-in-shell-script) related question, but was hoping there might be a way to do this without having to run make first.

I considered the possibility of somehow using grep on the Makefile, but some of the variables are defined across multiple lines, which makes it tricky and breakable (for instance, if I do grep -A 3 for a variable defined across 3 lines, what if a 4th line is added later?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TEST_ENV=$(make -qp | awk -F' = ' '$1=="TEST_ENV" {print $2}')
```

I'm sure there are edge cases this doesn't handle, but it's a decent start. Rudimentary testing shows this handles multi-line variables.

Comment: I wasn't able to use your awk-only example, the $1==VARNAME never had any matches. I did get this related idea to work though: TEST_ENV=$(make -qp | grep "TEST_ENV :=" | awk -F ' := ' '{print $2}'). Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Looks like for your example the awk line needs `-F' := '`.

Comment: I did initially change the '=' to ':=' and ' :=  ', but it still was giving no results.

Comment: Did you write `$1==VARNAME` or `$1=="VARNAME"`? The quotes are required.

Comment: It depends on whether the variable is defined with `=` (deferred)  or `:=` (immediate), so the correct `-F` argument is `-F ' :?= '` (although it is conceivable that the delimiter string will appear inside a variable definition). Note that make -p prints *definitions*, not values, so variables defined with `=` may have unexpanded variable references in the printed value.

Answer (score 2):

You could use (a modified version of) the `print-%` target from [Makefile hacks: print the value of any variable](http://blog.melski.net/2010/11/30/makefile-hacks-print-the-value-of-any-variable/) in your makefile to let you query it for values.

```
print-%:
        @echo '$(subst ','\'',$($*))'
```