# Makefile target output as input parameter to shell script

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have following Makefile target defined:

```
.PHONY: docker-build
docker-build:
    # Build Docker image
    docker build \
    --squash \
    ...
    -t $(DOCKER_IMAGE):$(DOCKER_TAG) .

output:
    @echo Docker Image: $(DOCKER_IMAGE):$(DOCKER_TAG)
```

I need to use the variables DOCKER_IMAGE and DOCKER_TAG as input for another script to run right after the `make docker-build`.

Do you have any idea how to do it? Thanks in advance.

I have tried many ways but can't get the output from Makefile to environment variables or even just to terminal.

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645340/using-makefile-variables-in-shell-script

Comment: You could A) add the `output` commands to the `docker-build` recipe, B) write the variables to a file which the output script -- or the output rule -- could read, or C) have the `docker-build` rule optionally call the `output` rule. Does any of those options appeal?

Comment: Just to elaborate on Beta's comment: it's not possible for the makefile to put environment variables into the shell that invoked `make`.  This has nothing to do with `make` or makefiles.  This is a fundamental feature of all POSIX programs: a program inherits its environment from its parent, and a program can never modify its parent's environment.  So, the shell is a program, it invokes make (another program), and it's not possible for the child (make) to modify the environment of the parent (shell).  Can't be done.